# How to figure out if git url point to the same repo?

Tags: git, url, clone

Below I have four git clone commands, where all three will be valid and clone the same repository, however they could all point to different repositories. I am curious if there is any way to standardize (some way of resolving them to the same id to note if they all point to the the same repo) these urls to know that they are all indeed the same repo. Is there any git command that can tell me a standardized url? Is there any way to check if they are the same repo without cloning? If not how would I check they are all the same with cloning?

```
git clone ssh://git@github.com/reggi/example.git
git clone ssh://git@github.com/reggi/example
git clone git@github.com/reggi/example.git
git clone git@github.com/reggi/example
```

Comment: What do you mean by "standardized"?

Comment: The only way to prove that they are indeed the same repository would be to push some object ref to one, and verify that it appears in the others.

Comment: @JoshLee wow really? I thought if you clone them all you can at least check the hash tree without having to push and check.

Comment: Just because `git upload-pack reggi/example` and `git upload-pack reggi/example.git` both produce the same content does not prove they are the same repository.

Comment: It proves that they are currently identical in content, but not that *new changes* will be propagated from one to the other.

Comment: And, just to throw a spanner into the works, even if you find that uploading stuff to `$URL_A` cause them to appear in `$URL_B` *right now*, that doesn't mean that uploading to `$URL_A` *tomorrow* will update `$URL_B` *tomorrow*. Fortunately the problem becomes easy when you define away all the hard parts, e.g., by constraining the URLs to GitHub URLs...

Answer (score 2):

It's really a matter of convention. The `.git` part is an optional convention, which is used by GitHub and (I believe) some other hosting sites.

However, anything on a different scheme is not guaranteed to access the same content. SSH and HTTP<sup>1</sup> schemes have very different notions of what a path means, and how it is defined.

<sup>1</sup> That is, in `http://git@github.com/some/url`, which is usually impicit.

Comment: That's the exact issue I am facing, the urls could point to different content. Is there no way to check the 303 redirect that they hit and see if they all point to the same place? Ideally something without cloning each? Or do I have to clone them and check?

Comment: A "uniform resource indicator," or in other words, a unique identifier for a given resource (repo) is defined by the scheme. So, if you use a different scheme, then it's a different resource, by definition. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier

Comment: In other words, the fact that it has the same content is guaranteed by GitHub, Inc; not by the structure of the URL. (There is some hope!)

Comment: I can't find a specific guarantee from GitHub (if that's what you're after), but here's the closest thing. It's the docs on [how to choose which remote url to use](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/#cloning-with-https-urls-recommended). There's an implicit promise that they all work as documented here.